# Channel Form : JS issue with date field

Tags: channel-form

If I set include_jquery="no" parameter I still appear to be getting JS code injected into my page as one of my fields is a date field.

Not including it is throwing two JS errors:

```
jQuery not defined and $ not defined.
```

If I include jQuery the errors go away but then the date field throws a weird value:

```
2014-05-22un22efine22
```

Questions:

1. If I have a field that EE recognizes as requiring a jQuery UI element will it always throw in the JS? Is there a way to override this?
2. If I do include jQuery how do I fix the weird date value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried adding `include_assets="no"` and `datepicker="no"`? These should stop Expression Engine including it's own JS.

Comment: Awesome, exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.